# How to have multiple imap servers installed (only one working) in CentOS

Tags: centos, imap, service, courier-imap

I have courier-imap currently installed on my CentOS server. I would like to install another imap server (such as dovecot) without uninstalling courier-imap, and then be able to switch between them, that is, so that I can try both and decide which one bets suits my needs, without always uninstalling one of them and installing the other one.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple IMAP servers installed in parallel.

You may select which IMAP server you'd like to run by starting it via the init script.

For example, to stop your courier-map issue:

```
# /etc/init.d/courier-imap stop
```

Note, I'm not running courier-imap so please double check on the init script name.

To install dovecot:

```
# yum -y install dovecot
```

To start dovecot:

```
# /etc/init.d/dovecot start
```

To make your changes persist across reboot, consult the man page for chkconfig.